# Finding TypeError subtracting two numpy.ndarrays of the same size and type

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find my sensor's relative position to the sun by subtracting the solar azimuth from the compass heading.  For testing purposes I have two numpy vectors.  One with the solar azimuth for 52 different samples and one with the compass for 52 different samples.

I do this kind of operand on numpy vectors all the time, so I don't know why it is giving me the following error.

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

This is some of the code, I'll try include as much as possible but it comes from a largish code base.

```
    ####STUFF above####

    # for debugging
    a = dalecData.get_solar_azimuth()
    b = dalecData.get_cmp_heading()

    print type(a)
    print type(b)

    print a.shape
    print b.shape

    print a.flags
    print b.flags

    print a.ndim
    print b.ndim

    a - b

    #work aroundS ????

    #sensorAzimuth = subract(dalecData.get_solar_azimuth(),dalecData.get_cmp_heading()) 
    #sensorAzimuth = asarray(dalecData.get_solar_azimuth()) -  asarray(dalecData.get_cmp_heading())## wtf?
    #for i in range(0,dalecData.get_solar_azimuth().shape[0]):
    #    sensorAzimuth[i] = dalecData.get_solar_azimuth()[i] - dalecData.get_cmp_heading()[i]
```

Gives me the following output

```
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
    (52, 1)
    (52, 1)
    C_CONTIGUOUS : True
    F_CONTIGUOUS : False
    OWNDATA : True
    WRITEABLE : True
    ALIGNED : True
    UPDATEIFCOPY : False
    C_CONTIGUOUS : True
    F_CONTIGUOUS : False
    OWNDATA : True
    WRITEABLE : True
    ALIGNED : True
    UPDATEIFCOPY : False
    2
    2
```

All of the 'workarounds' give the same error

The vectors are initialised using

```
    # viewing geometry
    self.__solarZenith = zeros((1))
    self.__solarAzimuth = zeros((1))
```

Accessors

```
    def get_solar_zenith(self):
        return self.__solarZenith


    def get_solar_azimuth(self):
        return self.__solarAzimuth

    def set_cmp_heading(self,value):
        self.__cmpHeading = value
```

And populated using

```
    row = self.findClosestDatetime(self.__edStartTime[i], self.__cmpDateTime)
    heading = vstack((heading, self.__cmpHeading[row-1]))
    heading = delete(heading,0,0) # get rid of initialised 0
    self.set_cmp_heading(heading)
```

This should resample the data to the edStartTime sample times.  And seems to work.

solar zenith and azimuth are calculated using pysolar http://pysolar.org/

All of the values seem to be correct, I just can't subtract the values from each other.  It only happens with these vectors.  I can add and subtract other vectors in the same manner elsewhere in my code.

I hope I have explained my situation.  I would appreciate help understanding the error.

Thanks

Comment: Check the types of elements in arrays you subtract

Comment: try checking also `a.dtype` and `b.dtype`

Comment: Are they string arrays by some strange chance?  If you do mathematical operations on string arrays (or structured arrays with a string field) you'll get the same error.  The same goes for any dtype (or python type) that doesn't support subtraction (though string arrays are the only one that I can think of off the top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

this looks like your array is an [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) You can check it by using `a.dtype` and `b.dtype` if the output looks like `dtype('float64')` them I am wrong, but if it looks like `[('f0', '<f8')]` then the elements of your array(s) are records with floats, not floats themselves, and numpy does not know how to operate them.

This for example:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> x.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> np.diff(x)
array([1, 1])
>>> x.dtype = np.dtype([('f0', '<i8')])
>>> np.diff(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 998, in diff
return a[slice1]-a[slice2]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```